# problems in adding keras layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am having problem in shape, how could i resolve this? What can I do ?

Here is the error message:

```
File "run_demo.py", line 116, in main
    model = get_crfrnn_model_def()

 File "./src/crfrnn_model.py", line 70, in get_crfrnn_model_def            
    score_fused = Add()([score2, score_pool4c])

ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3, 34, 4) (3, 34, 3)
```

Here is the code:

````py
def get_crfrnn_model_def():
    channels, height, weight = 3, 500, 500

    # Input
    input_shape = (height, weight, 3)
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Add plenty of zero padding
    x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(100, 100))(img_input)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='conv1_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool2', padding='same')(x)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool3', padding='same')(x)
    pool3 = x

    # VGG-16 convolution block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool4', padding='same')(x)
    pool4 = x

    # VGG-16 convolution block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool5', padding='same')(x)

    # Fully-connected layers converted to convolution layers
    x = Conv2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='fc6')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='fc7')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), padding='valid', name='score-fr')(x)
    print(x)
    # Deconvolution
    score2 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=2, name='score2')(x)
    print(score2)
    # Skip connections from pool4
    score_pool4 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool4')(pool4)
    score_pool4c = Cropping2D((5, 5),name='score-pool4c')(score_pool4)
    print('asd')
    print(score_pool4c)
    score_fused = Add()([score2, score_pool4c])
    score4 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=2, name='score4', use_bias=False)(score_fused)

    # Skip connections from pool3
    score_pool3 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool3')(pool3)
    score_pool3c = Cropping2D((9, 9))(score_pool3)

    # Fuse things together
    score_final = Add()([score4, score_pool3c])

    # Final up-sampling and cropping
    upsample = Conv2DTranspose(3, (16, 16), strides=8, name='upsample', use_bias=False)(score_final)
    upscore = Cropping2D(((31, 37), (31, 37)))(upsample)

    output = CrfRnnLayer(image_dims=(height, weight),
                         num_classes=3,
                         theta_alpha=160.,
                         theta_beta=3.,
                         theta_gamma=3.,
                         num_iterations=10,
                         name='crfrnn')([upscore, img_input]
    model = Model(img_input, output, name='crfrnn_net')
    return model```

'''
def get_crfrnn_model_def():
    channels, height, weight = 3, 500, 500
    input_shape = (3,height, weight)
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Add plenty of zero padding
    x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(100, 100))(img_input)
    # VGG-16 convolution block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='conv1_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool2', padding='same')(x)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool3', padding='same')(x)
    pool3 = x

    # VGG-16 convolution block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool4', padding='same')(x)
    pool4 = x

    # VGG-16 convolution block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool5', padding='same')(x)

    # Fully-connected layers converted to convolution layers
    x = Conv2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='fc6')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='fc7')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), padding='valid', name='score-fr')(x)

    # Deconvolution
    score2 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=2, name='score2')(x)

    # Skip connections from pool4
    score_pool4 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool4')(pool4)
    score_pool4c = Cropping2D((5, 5))(score_pool4)
    score_fused = Add()([score2, score_pool4c])
    score4 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=2, name='score4', use_bias=False)(score_fused)

    # Skip connections from pool3
    score_pool3 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool3')(pool3)
    score_pool3c = Cropping2D((9, 9))(score_pool3)

    # Fuse things together
    score_final = Add()([score4, score_pool3c])

    # Final up-sampling and cropping
    upsample = Conv2DTranspose(3, (16, 16), strides=8, name='upsample', use_bias=False)(score_final)
    upscore = Cropping2D(((31, 37), (31, 37)))(upsample)

    output = CrfRnnLayer(image_dims=(height, weight),
                         num_classes=3,
                         theta_alpha=160.,
                         theta_beta=3.,
                         theta_gamma=3.,
                         num_iterations=10,
                         name='crfrnn')([upscore, img_input])

    # Build the model
    model = Model(img_input, output, name='crfrnn_net')
    model.summary()
    return model
get_crfrnn_model_def()
````

my main file:

```
def getImageArr(path, width, height, imgNorm="sub_mean", odering='channels_first'):
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(path, 1)

        if imgNorm == "sub_and_divide":
            img = np.float32(cv2.resize(img, (width, height))) / 127.5 - 1
        elif imgNorm == "sub_mean":
            img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
            img = img.astype(np.float32)
            img[:, :, 0] -= 103.939
            img[:, :, 1] -= 116.779
            img[:, :, 2] -= 123.68
        elif imgNorm == "divide":
            img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
            img = img.astype(np.float32)
            img = img / 255.0

        if odering == 'channels_first':
            img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0)
        return img
    except Exception as e:
        print(path, e)
        img = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
        if odering == 'channels_first':
            img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0)
        return img


def getSegmentationArr(path, nClasses, width, height):
    seg_labels = np.zeros((height, width, nClasses))
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
        img = img[:, :, 0]

        for c in range(nClasses):
            seg_labels[:, :, c] = (img == c).astype(int)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    seg_labels = np.reshape(seg_labels, (width * height, nClasses))
    return seg_labels


def imageSegmentationGenerator(images_path, segs_path, batch_size, n_classes, input_height, input_width, output_height,
                               output_width):

    images = glob.glob(images_path + "*.jpg") 
    images.sort()

    segmentations = glob.glob(segs_path + "*.jpg") + glob.glob(segs_path + "*.png") + glob.glob(segs_path + "*.jpeg")
    segmentations.sort()

    assert len(images) == len(segmentations)
    zipped =itertools.cycle(zip(images, segmentations))

    while True:
        X = []
        Y = []
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            im,seg = next(zipped,(None,None))

            X.append(getImageArr(im, input_width, input_height))
            Y.append(getSegmentationArr(seg, n_classes, output_width, output_height))

def main():
    input_file = 'image.jpg'
    output_file = 'labels.png'
    saved_model_path = 'crfrnn_keras_model.h5'
    m = get_crfrnn_model_def()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]

    parser.add_argument("--epoch_number", type = int, default = 1 )
    parser.add_argument("--test_images", type = str , default = "/home/qwe/Downloads/leaf-image-segmentation-segnet-master/predict/0.png")
    parser.add_argument("--output_path", type = str , default = "/home/qwe/Downloads/leaf-image-segmentation-segnet-master/predictans")
    parser.add_argument("--input_height", type=int , default = 500 )
    parser.add_argument("--input_width", type=int , default = 500 )
    parser.add_argument("--optimizer_name", type=str, default="adadelta")              
    m.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adadelta',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    G = imageSegmentationGenerator('xtrain/', 'ytrain/', 8,3,
                                           input_height=500, input_width=500, output_height=500, output_width=500)
    for ep in range(1):
        m.fit_generator(G, 100, epochs=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my main file:

```
def getImageArr(path, width, height, imgNorm="sub_mean", odering='channels_first'):
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(path, 1)

        if imgNorm == "sub_and_divide":
            img = np.float32(cv2.resize(img, (width, height))) / 127.5 - 1
        elif imgNorm == "sub_mean":
            img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
            img = img.astype(np.float32)
            img[:, :, 0] -= 103.939
            img[:, :, 1] -= 116.779
            img[:, :, 2] -= 123.68
        elif imgNorm == "divide":
            img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
            img = img.astype(np.float32)
            img = img / 255.0

        if odering == 'channels_first':
            img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0)
        return img
    except Exception as e:
        print(path, e)
        img = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
        if odering == 'channels_first':
            img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0)
        return img


def getSegmentationArr(path, nClasses, width, height):
    seg_labels = np.zeros((height, width, nClasses))
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
        img = img[:, :, 0]

        for c in range(nClasses):
            seg_labels[:, :, c] = (img == c).astype(int)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    seg_labels = np.reshape(seg_labels, (width * height, nClasses))
    return seg_labels


def imageSegmentationGenerator(images_path, segs_path, batch_size, n_classes, input_height, input_width, output_height,
                               output_width):

    images = glob.glob(images_path + "*.jpg") 
    images.sort()

    segmentations = glob.glob(segs_path + "*.jpg") + glob.glob(segs_path + "*.png") + glob.glob(segs_path + "*.jpeg")
    segmentations.sort()

    assert len(images) == len(segmentations)
    zipped =itertools.cycle(zip(images, segmentations))

    while True:
        X = []
        Y = []
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            im,seg = next(zipped,(None,None))

            X.append(getImageArr(im, input_width, input_height))
            Y.append(getSegmentationArr(seg, n_classes, output_width, output_height))

def main():
    input_file = 'image.jpg'
    output_file = 'labels.png'
    saved_model_path = 'crfrnn_keras_model.h5'
    m = get_crfrnn_model_def()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]

    parser.add_argument("--epoch_number", type = int, default = 1 )
    parser.add_argument("--test_images", type = str , default = "/home/qwe/Downloads/leaf-image-segmentation-segnet-master/predict/0.png")
    parser.add_argument("--output_path", type = str , default = "/home/qwe/Downloads/leaf-image-segmentation-segnet-master/predictans")
    parser.add_argument("--input_height", type=int , default = 500 )
    parser.add_argument("--input_width", type=int , default = 500 )
    parser.add_argument("--optimizer_name", type=str, default="adadelta")              
    m.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adadelta',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    G = imageSegmentationGenerator('xtrain/', 'ytrain/', 8,3,
                                           input_height=500, input_width=500, output_height=500, output_width=500)
    for ep in range(1):
        m.fit_generator(G, 100, epochs=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that for an `Add()` operation the shapes must be equal. And they are: "(3, 34, 4) (3, 34, 3)"

For instance changing the kernel size in:

```
score_pool4 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool4')(pool4)
```

From 3 to 4, should fix this particular issue.